# Can you version control mySQL / postgres per user?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Just a hypothetical question at the moment, but can you version control DBs per user?

Let's say I'm the only tech person in a company, and they're planning to hire an IT apprentice.
Now said apprentice would also be working on the DB and manipulate data eventually...

Assume I've managed to not screw up any data in years by being very careful with every command, but who's to say the apprentice wouldn't send off a wrong statement that deletes a few rows too many for example?

Right now, the only option would be to restore a DB backup that's up to a week old.

Is there some sort of software or addon that will keep a backup of every changed row? Ideally on a per-user basis, so you could create an account for the apprentice that's version controlled, while changes coming from the frontend wouldn't be version controlled for example?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to knit something like that yourself with triggers and historical tables, but it is complicated and would cripple performance. There are also some problems that would be nigh impossible to solve: If the apprentice inserts a row and some other user a row that depends on the first row via foreign key, how can you undo changes per user?

In my opinion (and this question is opinion based) your best option is to

- implement a deployment pipeline (development - test - production)
- keep manual meddling with the database to an absolute minimum (which will also make your sleep better, since nobody is perfect)
- introduce a solution for automated base backups and WAL archiving with a simple and well-tested point-in-time-recovery option